# Javascript async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I tried XMLhttpRequest to get some data. But this give me this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'points1' of null
>           at doSomething (match.js:36)
>           at XMLHttpRequest.preGameRequest.onload (match.js:29)

I don't really know what's going on this code. I tried to figure it out on my own for an hour but got stuck.

What should I do?

```
preGameRequest.open("GET", "/matches/live.json");
preGameRequest.onload = function() {
    preGameData = JSON.parse(preGameRequest.responseText);
    doSomething();
}
// line 29 is here
preGameRequest.send();

function doSomething() {
    for (var i = 0; i < preGameData[0].length; i++) {
        // line 36 is here
        preGameData[0][i].points1 = {success: 0, total: 0};
        ...
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < preGameData[1].length; i++) {
        preGameData[1][i].points1 = {success: 0, total: 0};
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is in `preGameRequest.responseText`?

Comment: Well it is saying that `preGameData[0][i]` is null so I would start to debug there and find out why. Seems like this has nothing to do with the ajax call, seems like issue is with the data being returned and how you are accessing it. So show us your JSON.

Comment: It might be beneficial to include the contents of `live.json` in your question.

Comment: @BugHunterUK, why on earth should the code be deleted? I am little but surprised to see the heavy interest of editing this question ;( You are right about the JSON, no one is able to understand and answer this question without the most crucial and important part.

Comment: @davidkonrad Christ, you're right. I'm going to give up on this mod/editing thing. I keep messing it up.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your data it's impossible to pin point the cause of the error, but you can check in your code if it's `null` before attempting to set `points1`.

```
if (preGameData[0][i] !== null) {
  preGameData[0][i].points1 = {success: 0, total: 0};
}
```